# How do I get my Logitech Quickcam 4000 up and running?

Tags: debian, camera

I've just installed Debian “Squeeze” and would love it if I could get my webcam up and running.

I've Googled for a solution, and there's a package named `pwc` that I need to install to get it up and running (it's a Philips driver, but runs on my Logitech too if I am correct).

So, I did a `apt-cache search pwc` but the only result is

```
setpwc - program to set and query settings of (mainly) Philips WebCams.
```

So, how do I install the correct driver for my webcam?

Comment: It's more "unfamiliar" than "hard".

Comment: Try `luvcview` from the `luvcview` package, that works with my QuickCam Pro 9000.

Answer (score 1):

Have you just "tried it" ?   Linux often has the drivers you need already ready & waiting, usually you just need to plug it in.

A simple program to see what the camera's seeing is **Cheese**.  Look for that in your package manager (e.g. Synaptic) and install it.

Plug your camera in and start Cheese.

SMILE!!

Comment: Cheese does not work either. I got no webcam usb hardware listed up :(

Comment: Hmmm, "no webcam usb hardware" means the system isn't recognizing your webcam. `lsusb` should show something relating to the camera, but it does depend on the drivers.  The kernel module 'pwc' supports a range of usb prod:vend items, could you post your prod:vend values from the 'lsusb' output?  (looks like: 046D:08B1 (as an example))  You could also do `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and watch the output AS you plug in the camera, it could show some information pertaining to why the camera isn't being seen.